# Apex:commandButton action not being invoked

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am currently trying to create an app to track workouts and I've hit a snag.

I have a visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Exercise__c" extensions="ExerciseListController" recordSetVar="Exercises"  sidebar="true" showheader="false">
  <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock id="ExerciseList">
          <apex:pageBlockTable Value="{!Exercises}" var="e" rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(Exercises))}">
              <apex:column HeaderValue="Add to Wod" width="60">
                 <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!selected[e.id]}"/>
              </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Exercise Name">
                  <apex:outputLink value="/{!e.id}" target="_blank">
                      {!e.Name}
                  </apex:outputLink>
              </apex:column>
              <apex:column HeaderValue="Exercise ID">
                  <apex:outputLink value="/{!e.id}" target="_blank">
                      {!e.id}
                  </apex:outputLink>
              </Apex:column>
          </apex:pageBlockTable>
          <apex:outputLabel value="No record to display" rendered="{!(ISBLANK(Exercises))}" styleClass="noRowsHeader"></apex:outputLabel>
          <apex:pageBlockButtons >
              <apex:commandButton reRender="all" value="Save" action="{!SelectExercisesForWod}"/>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

and a controller extension:

```
public class ExerciseListController{

    public Map<Id, Boolean> selected {get; set;}

    List<Exercise__c> Exercises;

    public String WodID {get; set;}

    public ExerciseListController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {

    }

    public ApexPages.StandardSetController ExerciseListController{
        get{
            if(ExerciseListController == null) {
                 ExerciseListController= new apexPages.standardSetController(
                    Database.getQueryLocator(
                        [Select Name FROM Exercise__c]
                    )
                );    
            }
            return ExerciseListController;
        }
        set;
    }

    public pageReference SelectExercisesForWod(){
        system.debug('test');
        return null;
    }

    public List<Exercise__c> getExercises(){
        return (List<Exercise__c>) ExerciseListController.getRecords();
    }

    public void setExercises(Exercise__c[] exercises){
        this.exercises = exercises;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getItems(){
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        for(Exercise__c e : [select name from Exercise__c]){
            options.add(new selectOption(e.id, e.name));
        }
        return options;        
    }
}
```

When I click on the commandbutton in the page the action method does not fire. Their is no redirect and the system.debug does not show "test". Any clue why?

Comment: My (educated) guess is that you don't have your debug log levels set correctly. You need to have a SYSTEM level of at least DEBUG in order to see the System.debug message. Your action method certainly should be called and completed successfully.

Comment: I'm still new to this so im not 100% what you mean. I never went in to change any debug log levels so what ever the default is for a sandbox should be what they are set at currently.

When I moved the PageReference into the controller, the page stops redirecting, so it's not just the debug that isn't working. Looks like the whole method is not being called.

Comment: @CullenSullivan [Standard List Controller Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals/visualforce_standard_list_controllers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres how I'd write the page from looking at your code. Unless you have a good reason to use it, I'd drop the standard controller, the standard set controller, and some other code. I assume theres some reason for functions like `getOptions` but since they're unused for the demo you posted I removed them.

So first off, I'm using a custom controller, with a wrapper class to hold the `selected` value. You could use the standard controller, but Im generally not a fan of it. The custom controller gets its own data & doesn't create a standard Controller (its usually overkill at that point). I modified your save method to set a fake id from the WodID on the selected records & the return either a page error or a fake results page.

The key point here - don't mix and match custom / standard code. Don't create a page using the standard controller, but also using the standardSetController, but not using the one passed along in the controller, instead you created a totally separate setController and then didn't use any of its functions (such as standard save, standard selected, or pagination). Try to avoid names overlapping with each other too. Don't make getters/ setters that are external to the variable. Use the same data in all places - the standard controller, the getOptions method, and your own controller data.

---

Rewritten to use a component instead of a page. Compatible with standard set controller & other callers.

## Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Exercise__c" recordSetVar="Exercises">
  <c:ExerciseList records_param="{!selected}" />
</apex:page>
```

## Component

```
<apex:component allowDml="true" controller="ExerciseListController">
    <apex:attribute name="records_param" type="List<Exercise__c>" assignTo="{!Records}" description="Records from Standard Set Controller" required="true" /> 

    <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock id="ExerciseList">
      <!-- Important to have page messages in rerender area -->
      <apex:pageMessages />
          <apex:pageBlockTable Value="{!Exercises}" var="e" rendered="{!Excercise.size > 0}">
              <apex:column HeaderValue="Add to Wod" width="60">
              <!-- Uses its own property & not a map, either way is fine tbh --> 
                 <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!e.Selected}"/>
              </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Exercise Name">
                  <apex:outputLink value="/{!e.id}" target="_blank">
                      {!e.Name}
                  </apex:outputLink>
              </apex:column>
              <!-- removed dupe column can easily add it back --> 
          </apex:pageBlockTable>
          <!-- can directly acces size of list on page --> 
          <apex:outputLabel value="No record to display" rendered="{!Excercise.size == 0}" styleClass="noRowsHeader"></apex:outputLabel>
          <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <!-- make sure your rerender points to a named panel --> 
              <apex:commandButton reRender="ExerciseList" value="Select" action="{!SelectExercisesForWod}"/>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

## Controller

```
public class ExerciseListController {

    // wrapper holds all data & extra, page only data we add to class 
    public class ExerciseWrapper {
        // returns based on given object 
        public Id Id { get { return Exercise.Id; } }
        public String Name { get { return Exercise.Name; } }

        // Custom value to store selected wrapper values 
        public Boolean Selected { get; set; }

        // Source of data, made public to access any fields not given above
        // can set just setter to private 
        public Exercise__c Exercise { get; private set; }

        public ExerciseWrapper(Exercise__c Exercise) {
            this.Exercise = Exercise; 
            this.selected = false; 
        }
    }

    // set via param 
    public List<Exercise__c> Records { get; set; }

    public List<ExerciseWrapper> Exercises { 
        get {
            // Null Check Records 
            if (Excersizes == null) {
                Exercises = new List<Exercise__c>();

                for (Exercise__c e : Records) {
                    Exercises.add(new ExerciseWrapper(e));
                }
            }
        }
        set; 
    }

    public String WodID { get {
        if (WodID == null) {
            // assume set somewhere not set in your code 
            WodId = (Id)ApexPages.CurrentPage.getParameters.get('WodID');
        }

        return WodID;
    } set; } 

    // params are not set at constructor time 
    public ExerciseListController() {}

    public pageReference SelectExercisesForWod() { 
        List<Exercise__c> udpateList = new List<Exercise__c>(); 

        for (ExerciseWrapper wrapper : Exercises) {
            if (wrapper.Selected) {
                // assume your setting some fields 
                Exercise__c e = wrapper.Exercise;
                // get records, set some field to given id 
                e.Wod_Id__c = WodId; 
                // add to update list 
                udpateList.add(e);
            }
        }

        // add page message "you must select at least one record" if size == 0

        try {
            // try update 
            update updateList; 
            // return to dummy result page 
            return new PageReference('/apex/someResultPage');
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Set error on returned page 
            ApexPages.CurrentPage.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(e));
        }
        // refreshes page & would show error in page message 
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

Move your `oncomplete` return into your action, so its returned when the server is done.

```
public pageReference SelectExercisesForWod(){
    insert someData; // youll probably want to return a conditional value based on your save result anyway 

    return new PageReference('/');
}
```

You could try to do both, but really you're only going to redirect to a single page at a time. Trying to use both `oncomplete` and `return pageRef` is asking for problems.

Comment: That was my thought too initially, but I realized that it's not actually the case. oncomplete will be called after the button performs the server-side logic. I still agree with your recommendation of using PageReference instead, though.

Comment: I have followed your recommendation. Still nothing, now it doesnt even redirect

Comment: Is it crashing or is it staying on the same page ?

Comment: Staying on the same page

Comment: `return PageReference('\')` was just short hand for whatever url you wanted to return, I assumed there was a valid url that you removed due to privacy concerns. To refresh the page just return null.

Comment: You should just use the standard controller save method on your page, unless you have specific behavior that has to happen on save (not mentioned in your post).

Comment: Did you pass the valid page name like `return new PageReference('/apex/YourPageName');`

Comment: Eventually I will have specific behavior and a page that I want to redirect to. I havent gotten that far yet. For now I just want to figure out why this method is not being called. I have changed it back to return null in the controller for now.

Comment: Oh um, its probably your rerender. Its `rerender="all"` but I don't see anything named `all`. Try changing it to `ExerciseList` or just removing the rerender (it'll rerender the whole page instead, unless you tell it to go to a specific page).

Comment: Add a `<apex:pageMessages />` too, if theres an error anywhere it won't show without the message section.

Comment: Ok I am attempting to do it this way, however eventually this will be attached to a custom list button, so I believe I need to have the custom and standard controller in order to do that. I want a user to be able to go to a related list in a workout detail page and select multiple records from a list of exercises.

Comment: The last time I needed to use the standard set controller was in a similar case - changing one or more leads owners. I used a solution where the user would pick leads from the list view, and then click the button. The page itself was just a container for a vf component that held the controller & all the actual code. The page just passed along the selected ids like so:  `<c:LeadChangeOwner recordsParameter="{!selected}" />`. You kind of get the best of both worlds here - you get to use the Standard Set controller & a custom controller.

Comment: @CullenSullivan See my edit for an example. Weird to have a user pick some records & then pick again from those records but hey its not my UI & this is really more of a demo anyway.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work. Ended up using most of this post's original code. I did not end up needing the standard or list controller, just needed to make a few tweaks. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass the page name when initializing the `PageReference`.

So, your controller code should be

```
public PageReference SelectExercisesForWod(){ 
    // Your code goes here
    return new PageReference('/apex/YourPageName'); 
}
```

Or you can set the page name directly, so that it verifies the page name at compile time.

```
public PageReference SelectExercisesForWod(){ 
    // Your code goes here
    return Page.YourPageName; 
}
```

If you currently don't have any visualforce page created, then I would advice you to create a dummy page to which you can redirect and can refer that dummy page till the time you create the actual page.

```
public PageReference SelectExercisesForWod(){ 
    // Your code goes here
    return Page.DummyPage; 
}
```

Also make sure that development mode is switched OFF when testing this, as redirect might not happen properly when development mode is ON.

Comment: `return Page.YourPageName;` is arguably better as it guarantees compile time check

Comment: Yup updated the answer. Thanks @cropredy